# How to make these two alternatives about looping on cartesian product less redundant?

Tags: python, loops, cartesian-product

In the following function `f`, we can either loop on `a` first or on `b` first.

**How to make its code less redundant?**

```
def myfunction(a):
    pass

def f(first_loop_on_a=True):
    if first_loop_on_a:
        for a in range(10):
            A = "%010i" % a               
            myfunction(a)
            for b in range(5):
                print A, b
    else:
        for b in range(5):
            for a in range(10):
                A = "%010i" % a
                myfunction(a)
                print A, b

f(True)
f(False)
```

I was thinking about [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), but still, we would have:

```
def myfunction2(a, b):
    A = "%010i" % a               
    myfunction(a)
    print A, b

def f(first_loop_on_a=True):
    if first_loop_on_a:
        for a, b in product(range(10), range(5)):
            myfunction2(a, b)
    else:
        for b, a in product(range(5), range(10)):
            myfunction2(a, b)
```

which is still a bit redundant.

Comment: Your first option calls `myfunction` a lot less than your second. Is this important? It's not clear whether `myfunction` is supposed to represent a function used for its side effects or its return value.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes it *would* be important. But as it was already difficult to find an answer, I didn't add this as a criteria, but ideally yes, it's important to have less calls, at least in the `for a, for b` order (in the other order, it's impossible, so we cannot do anything about it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a generator expression to flip the tuples when you do the `product` with the source of the `b` values first:

```
def f(first_loop_on_a=True):
    if first_loop_on_a:
        gen = product(range(10, range(5))
    else:
        gen = (a, b for b, a in product(range(5), range(10)))

    for a, b in gen:
        myfunction2(a, b)
```

I would note that this is still not the same as your original function, since in the original, `myfunction` gets called a different number of times between the two branches (either 10 times or 50). The new function always calls it (via `myfunction2`) in the inner loop, so it will always be run 50 times.

Answer (score 1):

If your function is too repetitive, you can refactor things step by step.

The commonality you want to factor out is calling `myfunction2(a, b)` on some iterator. But the second iterator not only has the `product` args reversed, but the elements of each pair as well. So:

```
def f(first_loop_on_a=True):
    if first_loop_on_a:
        prod = product(range(10), range(5))
    else:
        prod = (b, a for (a, b) in product(range(5), range(10)))
    for a, b in prod:
        myfunction2(a, b)
```

---

If you're doing this multiple times, you can factor out that tuple-flipping into a function:

```
def flippair(p):
    a, b = p
    return b, a
def f(first_loop_on_a=True):
    if first_loop_on_a:
        prod = product(range(10), range(5))
    else:
        prod = map(flippair, product(range(5), range(10)))
    for a, b in prod:
        myfunction2(a, b)
```

(Or, of course, `flippair` could just return `p[::-1]`—or, since you don't need tuples, but just any kind of iterable, just use `reversed`. But this way seems more explicit, and still easily concise enough.)

---

But I think the best solution is to use keyword arguments for `myfunction`:

```
def kwify(order, pairs):
    return (dict(zip(order, pair)) for pair in pairs)
def f(first_loop_on_a=True):
    if first_loop_on_a:
        prod = kwify('ab', product(range(10), range(5)))
    else:
        prod = kwify('ba', product(range(5), range(10)))
    for kwpair in prod:
        myfunction2(**kwpair)
```

This makes it really obvious that you're passing `a` values as `a` and `b` values as `b`, rather than flipping them so they end up in `b` and `a` and then flipping them back to pass them in reverse order.

---

While we're at it, why repeat the ranges?

```
def kwify(order, pairs):
    return (dict(zip(order, pair)) for pair in pairs)
def f(first_loop_on_a=True):
    arange, brange = range(10), range(5)
    if first_loop_on_a:
        prod = kwify('ab', product(arange, brange))
    else:
        prod = kwify('ba', product(brange, arange))
    for kwpair in prod:
        myfunction2(**kwpair)
```

---

… at which point you can give *them* names as well:

```
def kwify(order, pairs):
    return (dict(zip(order, pair)) for pair in pairs)
def f(first_loop_on_a=True):
    ranges = {'a': range(10), 'b': range(5)}
    order = 'ab' if first_loop_on_a else 'ba'
    prod = kwify(order, product(*itemgetter(*order)(ranges)))
    for kwpair in prod:
        myfunction2(**kwpair)
```

---

… or, maybe even factor out the calls to `range`:

```
def kwify(order, pairs):
    return (dict(zip(order, pair)) for pair in pairs)
def f(first_loop_on_a=True):
    ranges = {'a': 10, 'b': 5}
    order = 'ab' if first_loop_on_a else 'ba'
    prod = kwify(order, product(*map(range, itemgetter(*order)(ranges))))
    for kwpair in prod:
        myfunction2(**kwpair)
```

This is probably horrible overkill for just choosing "a-then-b" vs. "b-then-a", but if you wanted this to extend to choosing different permutations of three variables, or arbitrary orders from a dynamic list, etc., it would probably be worth doing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to encourage that sort of frivolity, but who cares (+1). May I challenge you to make the last one work with either `myfunc(**kwtuple)` or `myfunc(*kwtuple.values()`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer If someone wants this because `myfunc` can’t be rewritten to take keyword arguments, `*(v for k, v in sorted(kwdict.items()))` is about the best I can think of on the fly. But that seems to step well over the line between clever and silly that I was already dancing on (not to mention that it depends on the fact that `'a'<'b'`).

Comment: I just realized what was bothering me about this code: `partial(zip, order)` is a nicely mappable function in its own right, so in my head I was thinking of… basically `partial(map, partial(zip, order))` as a reusable function. Which is how you’d probably write this in Haskell, but pretty far from Pythonic. I didn’t even realize I was thinking in those terms, but that’s exactly why it feels “too clever to actually use”.

Answer (score 0):

You could map through `reversed`:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> 
>>> def itr(A, B, a_first=True):
...     return it.product(*map(range, (A, B))) if a_first else map(reversed, it.product(*map(range, (B, A))))
... 
>>> [(a, b) for a, b in itr(2, 3, True)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
>>> [(a, b) for a, b in itr(2, 3, False)]
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```